# IBM MobileFirst - How to configure authenticationConfig.xml

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

My backend system has 2/3 servlets that need to be invoked in order to authenticate.

1. Validate a User ID
2. Possibly receive a challenge question (This is on a user by user basis)
3. Validate a password

I have set up my authenticationConfig.xml as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:loginConfiguration xmlns:tns="http://www.worklight.com/auth/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

     <staticResources>

        <resource id="subscribeServlet" securityTest="SubscribeServlet">
            <urlPatterns>/subscribeSMS*;/receiveSMS*;/ussd*</urlPatterns>
        </resource>

    </staticResources> 

     <securityTests>

        <customSecurityTest name="ValidateUserId-securityTest">
            <test realm="ValidateUserIdRealm" isInternalUserID="true"/>     
        </customSecurityTest>

        <customSecurityTest name="Challenge-securityTest">
            <test realm="ValidateUserIdRealm" isInternalUserID="true"/>
            <test realm="ValidateChallengeRealm"/>
        </customSecurityTest>

        <customSecurityTest name="Authenticated-securityTest">
            <test realm="ValidateUserIdRealm" isInternalUserID="true"/>
            <test realm="ValidateChallengeRealm"/>
            <test realm="ValidatePasswordRealm"/>
        </customSecurityTest>

        <customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
            <test realm="SubscribeServlet" isInternalUserID="true"/>
        </customSecurityTest>           

    </securityTests> 

    <realms>

        <realm name="ValidateUserIdRealm" loginModule="ValidateUserIdLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-function" value="AuthAdapter.validateUserId"/>
            <parameter name="logout-function" value="AuthAdapter.onLogout"/>
        </realm>

        <realm name="ValidateChallengeRealm" loginModule="ValidateChallengeLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-function" value="AuthAdapter.validateChallenge"/>
            <parameter name="logout-function" value="AuthAdapter.onLogout"/>
        </realm>

        <realm name="ValidatePasswordRealm" loginModule="ValidatePasswordLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-function" value="AuthAdapter.validatePassword"/>
            <parameter name="logout-function" value="AuthAdapter.onLogout"/>
        </realm>

        <realm name="SubscribeServlet" loginModule="rejectAll">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>          
        </realm>

    </realms>

    <loginModules>

        <loginModule name="ValidateUserIdLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule name="ValidateChallengeLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule name="ValidatePasswordLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule name="StrongDummy" expirationInSeconds="-1">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule name="requireLogin" expirationInSeconds="-1">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule name="rejectAll">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.RejectingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

    </loginModules>

</tns:loginConfiguration>
```

My end goal here is to utilize the MobileFirst server for two native applications (Android & iOS). I want to perform the authentication how the documentation explains it (Register challenge handlers for the different realms so the application can decide how to collect the information).

AuthAdapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
    5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
    US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
    disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
-->
<wl:adapter name="AuthAdapter"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:wl="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration"
    xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http">

    <displayName>AuthAdapter</displayName>
    <description>AuthAdapter</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>rss.cnn.com</domain>
            <port>80</port> 
            <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
            <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific certificate from key store  
            <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> 
            <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>
            -->     
        </connectionPolicy>
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="validateUserId" securityTest="ValidateUserId-securityTest">
        <displayName>Validate User ID</displayName>
    </procedure>

    <procedure name="validateChallenge" securityTest="Challenge-securityTest">
        <displayName>Validate Challenge Answer</displayName>
    </procedure>

    <procedure name="validatePassword" securityTest="Authenticated-securityTest">
        <displayName>Validate Password</displayName>
    </procedure>

</wl:adapter>
```

AuthAdapter-impl

```
function validateUserId(headers, errorMessage){
    errorMessage = errorMessage ? errorMessage : null;

    WL.Logger.info("onValidateUserId Called!");

    return {
        authRequired : true,
        errorMessage : errorMessage
    };

}

function validateChallenge(headers, errorMessage){
    errorMessage = errorMessage ? errorMessage : null;

    WL.Logger.info("onValidateChallenge Called!");

    return {
        authRequired : true,
        errorMessage : errorMessage
    };

}

function validatePassword(headers, errorMessage){
    errorMessage = errorMessage ? errorMessage : null;

    WL.Logger.info("onValidatePassword Called!");

    return {
        authRequired : true,
        errorMessage : errorMessage
    };

}

function onLogout(){
    WL.Logger.debug("Logged out");
}
```

What would be the proper way of implementing this?

Comment: Have you implemented this? or you are asking if we can implement your request?

Comment: @HussamEddin I have implemented this. For instance, if I call the validateChallenge() function inside of validateUserId() function it does not invoke my registered challengeHandler on the client application to collect the Challenge answer from the user.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first look at your `authenticationConfig.xml`.

I see you created 3 separate security tests. I don't think it makes sense for you if I understand your request correctly. A resource (an adapter, or an entire application) are protected by a single security test. Usually you create separate security tests when each resource requires a different authentication.

Also, I don't think you need 3 realms here. The 3 "tests" are tightly coupled. You can't check the password or answer without the username. So I think one single security test with one realm is enough for you.

Your adapter can have a single authentication procedure that will check both the username and the password.

For an example with an extra question (such as security question), see this: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-topics/two-step-adapter-authentication/